# Stacked bins for 4 labels : only two labels appear

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, stacked-chart

l have stacked bins of 7 bins which are :

```
labels = ['Digits', 'digits+spec-char', 'letters', 'letters+digit','letters+special-char','All-alphabet','All-alphabet(lower+upper)']
```

for 4 labels which are :

```
'CRNN', 'CRNN+transfer learning','CRNN+Image aug','CRNN+ Img Aug+ transfer learning'
```

my plot works but shows bins only for `CRNN+transfer learning` and `CRNN+ Img Aug+ transfer learning` as it's depicted in the following plot.
[image: plot]

Here is my code :

```
def bins_accuracy():
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter



    N = 7
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
    CRNN = (94.52,93.27, 94.34, 94.51,93.43,94.26,90)

    CRNN_transfer = (96.40,96.61,97.40,96.99,93.50,95.69,92.65)
    CRNN_img_aug=(0,0,0,0,0,94,92)
    CRNN_img_aug_transfer=(0,0,0,0,0,95,93)


    ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
    width = 0.35  # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
    labels = ['Digits', 'digits+spec-char', 'letters', 'letters+digit','letters+special-char','All-alphabet','All-alphabet(lower+upper)']
    p1 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN, width)
    p2 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_transfer, width)
    p3 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_img_aug, width)
    p4 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_img_aug_transfer, width)

    plt.ylabel('Accuracy %')
    plt.title('Accuracy by group')
    plt.xticks(ind, ('Digits', 'digits+spec-char', 'letters', 'letters+digit','letters+special-char','All-alphabet','All-alphabet(lower+upper)'))
    plt.ylim(ymax=99, ymin=91)
    plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0],p3[0],p4[0]), ('CRNN', 'CRNN+transfer learning','CRNN+Image aug','CRNN+ Img Aug+ transfer learning'))

    plt.show()
```

**What l want to see in my plot is** stacked bins for the four group
'CRNN', 'CRNN+transfer learning','CRNN+Image aug','CRNN+ Img Aug+ transfer learning' so 4 colors rather than only two

**EDIT1**
l got the following after adding :

OCR_Engine = (97.12, 97.68, 96.76, 96.64, 96.30, 96.51, 96.11)
p5 = plt.bar(ind + 4 * width, OCR_Engine, width)

[image: output]

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to provide more information about the format of your data. Right now, if you were to stack the bars, the values do not add up to 100%. For example the first bar would be 94.52+96.40+0+0 = 190.92%?

Comment: @DizietAsahi, each  value represent accuracy in % .

Comment: I realize that, but if you stack the bars on top of each other, their height would add up to more than 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you are plotting the bars directly on top of each other. You can stack the bars by setting the `bottom` key-word:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=7

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

CRNN = np.array([94.52,93.27, 94.34, 94.51,93.43,94.26,90])
CRNN_transfer = np.array([96.40,96.61,97.40,96.99,93.50,95.69,92.65])
CRNN_img_aug = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,94,92])
CRNN_img_aug_transfer= np.array([0,0,0,0,0,95,93])

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence
p1 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_transfer, width, bottom=CRNN)
p3 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_img_aug, width, bottom=CRNN+CRNN_transfer)
p4 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN_img_aug_transfer, width, bottom=CRNN+CRNN_transfer+CRNN_img_aug)

plt.show()
```

[image]

## EDIT:

If you want the bars side by side, you simply have to adjust the x-positions.

```
# side-by-side
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ind = np.arange(0, 2*N, 2)  # the x locations for the groups
p1 = plt.bar(ind, CRNN, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind+width, CRNN_transfer, width)
p3 = plt.bar(ind+2*width, CRNN_img_aug, width)
p4 = plt.bar(ind+3*width, CRNN_img_aug_transfer, width)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Paul. Thank you but the y-axis values should be at most 100% percent since the values are between 90% and 100%

Comment: I am telling you how to stack bars. I can't fix your data. Maybe, you don't want to to actually stack the bars, but rather plot them side by side?

Comment: l think so . For this probelm it's more appropriate to put them side by side

Comment: FYI: "stacked bar graph" refers to a graph with the bars on top of each other.

Comment: Thank you @Paul, it works. One last question, if l would like to add a fifth group Engine = (97.12, 97.68, 96.76, 96.64, 96.30, 96.51, 96.11), p5 = plt.bar(ind + 4 * width, Engine, width). l get this group separated from the the forth groups , there is an empty space

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Is the problem that the 5th bar is not flush with the other bars for your first five input types (it should be flush with the last 2)?

Comment: Please see my  EDIT1. l get the fifth bar  (ocr engine) far froth the four group

Comment: Well, the values for you 3rd and 4th bar are zero for the first four input types. So the 5th bar is in the right place, you just don't have anything filling the space in-between, making it look like it stands apart. I would just increase the step size in `ind`. E.g. `ind = np.arange(0, 4*N, 4). That way, it is still clear that you have missing values for the first four input types, but the grouping of the bars is better. Also, I would adjust the xtick label positions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Paul